# Oracle Forms and Reports 6i on Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu, oracleforms, oraclereports

I'm actually using Oracle Forms and Report 6i in Windows 32bits with Oracle Database 10g, and i want to change to Linux (Ubuntu) with the same versions.

After hours of researches i didn't find any helpful information about this, I only found the [10g version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/developer-suite/downloads/101202linuxsoft-099233.html%22Official%20website%20of%20Oracle%22) of the developer on the official website of Oracle and for the [6i version](http://naeemsheeraz.blogspot.com/2010/01/installing-developer-6i-on-ubuntu.html%226i%20version%22) most what i found use [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/%22wine%22) and i don't want to use it or any other Emulator type utility for the purpose.

I thought about migrating my application to 12c, but it's going to take me a lot of time.

My application contains:

- Over 900 .fmb/fmx files.
- Over 700 .rep/rdf files.

Is there any quicker way to have my application that is developed on 6i work in Linux?

[EDIT]

I have found a [tar file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bd8p3m3hhpi3nwf/d2k6irelease2.tar?dl=0) of oracle forms and reports 6i, i still haven't tried it, but does that mean there is forms 6i in linux? if so, is it going to work properly or what?

Any information whatsoever will be helpful!

Comment: Forms 6i FMX files are Windows binaries. So you have exactly the same problem as trying to use MS Word or any other Windows native software on Linux. It's WINE or redevelopment.

Comment: @APC what if i recompile the fmb files on linux,  wouldn't that work without having to redevelop?

Comment: Do you have a Forms compiler for Linux?

Comment: @APC I don't understand your question, From Oracle forms Builder i can compile my forms, won't that work on linux if i have it installed there?

Comment: Okay, I'll rephrase my question. Do you have a Forms Builder 6i for Linux?

Comment: @APC That's what i'm asking for in my first question, is there a Forms Builder 6i for Linux ( ubuntu) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149811/discussion-between-zenami-and-apc).

Comment: Sorry, I can't use chat at work. AFAIK Forms Builder is purely for Windows, even in 12c. If you migrate to web-enabled Forms then you can run the Forms in any browser on any platform. But with client/server Forms it's Windows or WINE.

Comment: @APC but how do you create forms in linux? must be a forms builder in linux no? Please check the edited version of the question